# Flex box space-between margins with space-around wrapping behavior

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am making a site that will have three cards and to create them I'm using flex box. I am using `justify-content: space-between` which works perfectly when the three columns are all on the same row, as their margins are perfect with the container, and the space in-between them is great.

However, when the columns wrap, the column that is now on the new row is at the same left margin as the first, which is expected with `space-between`, but in my scenario, `space-around`'s wrap behavior would look much better, as I have and odd number of cards.

Is there a way for me to get `space-between`'s outer margin alignment with `space-around`'s wrapping behavior?

Here is a codepen that gives a quick example of what I have now.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xdrpEo

```css
  .flex-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: spacing-between;
}

    .file-links-flex-container {
      max-width: 400px;
      flex-grow: 1;
      background-color: red;
      
}
      
              .container-content {
          justify-content: flex-start;
                        padding: 0 30px;
        max-height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row space-around">
        <div class="file-links-flex-container col">
          <div class="container-header">
            <h5>A</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="container-content">
            <p>I AM TEST CONTENT!</P>
          </div>
        </div>
          <div class="file-links-flex-container col">
          <div class="container-header">
            <h5>B</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="container-content">
            <p>I AM TEST CONTENT!</P>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="file-links-flex-container col">
          <div class="container-header">
            <h5>C</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="container-content">
            <p>I AM TEST CONTENT!</P>
          </div>
        </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Have you miss spelled space-between to "spacing-between" in your code too or only on the codepen?

Comment: Try adding `margin: 0 auto;`  to `file-links-flex-container` class. You get that.

Comment: You could use a media query to swap the value for `justify-content` at the point the cards begin to wrap.

Comment: @AshwinMothilal good catch on the typo, and hungerstar is there a dynamic way I can apply it when the flex wrap occurs? I'm not sure if a breakpoint will work nicely on all screens

Comment: Solved it using `space-between` on the container and a `margin: 0 auto` breakpoint on the `last-of-type` element. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding margin: 0 auto, You get that.

```
.file-links-flex-container{
     margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I think this one helped you. :)
Even you can solve this one using `justify-content:center;` but margin will be the good one.